# How to remove strings from mid-row column values in unix

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a 50 GB size text `file` like below. I want to remove chr from 1st and 3rd columns skipping any lines that start with `#`. I know I could add chr this way, but not sure how to remove them `cat ${file}.txt | awk -F"\t" '{if ($0 !~ /^#/) {print "chr"$0} else{print $0}}' > ${file}_moreCHR.txt`

`file:`

```
##contig=<ID=HLA-DRB1*>
##reference=file:////Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta
##source=ApplyVQSR
##source=SelectVariants
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    
chr1    69511   chr1:69511:A:G  A       G       11157600        PASS   
chr1    69536   chr1:69536:C:A  C       A       581.98  PASS    
chr1    69536   chr1:69536:C:T  C       T       581.98  PASS
```

Result I want:

```
##contig=<ID=HLA-DRB1*>
##reference=file:////Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta
##source=ApplyVQSR
##source=SelectVariants
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    
    1    69511   1:69511:A:G  A       G       11157600        PASS   
    1    69536   1:69536:C:A  C       A       581.98  PASS    
    1    69536   1:69536:C:T  C       T       581.98  PASS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"}                            # set delimiters to a tab
    !/^#/ {sub("^chr", "", $1); sub("^chr", "", $3)}    # if the line does not start with "#", modify the 1st and 3rd column
    1                                                   # print the line
' ${file}.txt > ${file}_lessCHR.txt
```

Result:

```
##contig=<ID=HLA-DRB1*>
##reference=file:////Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta
##source=ApplyVQSR
##source=SelectVariants
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO
1   69511   1:69511:A:G A   G   11157600    PASS
1   69536   1:69536:C:A C   A   581.98  PASS
1   69536   1:69536:C:T C   T   581.98  PASS
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding more generic solution here, give all the columns numbers in variable `cols` and we need not to write substitution so many times, try following.

```
awk -v cols="1,3" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="\t"
  num=split(cols,arr1,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    columns[arr1[i]]
  }
}
!/^#/{
  for(j in columns){
    sub(/^chr/,"",$j)
  }
}
1
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v cols="1,3" '           ##Starting awk program from here, creating cols which has all column numbers 1 and 3 comma separated here.
BEGIN{                        ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  num=split(cols,arr1,",")    ##Splitting cols variable into arr1 with comma separated.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){        ##Running for loop till value of num here.
    columns[arr1[i]]          ##Creating columns which has index as value of arr1 array here.
  }
}
!/^#/{                        ##Checking condition if line does not starts with # then do following.
  for(j in columns){          ##Going through columns here.
    sub(/^chr/,"",$j)         ##Substituting starting string chr with NULL in column $j.
  }
}
1                             ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove 'chr' no matter where it occurs on the line, this will remove the 'chr' strings and then not print lines that start with a hash mark:

```
sed -e 's/chr//g' ${file}.txt | grep -v '^#' > ${file}_noCHR.txt
```

If your lines have 'chr' in other columns that you don't want to remove, you'd need to modify the sed regular expression a bit.

Comment: How do you pipe this with cat? I need to open the file with `cat`

Comment: The expected output given by the OP indicates that the lines beginning with `#` are to be kept on the output.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin You're right about the comments appearing in the output -- I assumed that the output was shown incorrectly.

Comment: @New_to_R I'm not sure what you mean by 'open the file with cat'.  If you want the results of the sed and grep to be piped into cat then you could replace the '> ${file}_noCHR.txt' with '| cat ' etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^chr(\S+\s+\S+\s+)chr/    \1/' file
```

This will only change lines beginning `chr`.

Can be made part of pipe line:

```
cat oldFile | sed -E 's/^chr(\S+\s+\S+\s+)chr/    \1/' > newFile
```